# Фильтрация ссылок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, фильтры, фильтрация, фильтр

Есть к примеру массив `$array = array('blacksite.com',...);` в котором указаны запрещённые сайты, которые нужно фильтровать из текста, например заменять из на {Ссылка удалена} и можно проверять к примеру через regexp и после проходом `in_array()`, но зная что есть такая защита могут написать и `blacksite*com` и `blacksite com` или с пробелом или `*` после любой буквы в слове `blacksite`, как правильнее и лучше\надёжнее фильтровать?

UPD: Спасибо всем! Приму все ответы в использование, всже склонен к regexp так как чуть лучше но чуть затратнее

Comment: могут и часть букв русскими написать и в коментариях пометить что бы перепечатали буквы. Так же могут использовать сервисы сокращения ссылок или ip адреса. все не отфильтруете в любом случае. Для начала надо конкретизировать задачу, описать все возможные варианты написания. после чего на это уже делать регулярку

Comment: Может лучше вместо кучи меток с фильтрами поставить 1 метку `spam`?

Comment: Да дело в том что это отлично решает проблему если сайта нет в списке запрещённых, но если же он есть и им напишут достаточное кол-во записей? и пользователь перейдет и введёт там что либо и др? должна же быть какая то защита хотя бы от простого написания без пробелов и *  и др

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуть чуть оффтоп.

Все-таки я не согласен с ответом @Naumov. Я считаю, что лучше использовать регулярные выражения для фильтрации черных списков. Тем более их (функций) выполнение в PHP 7 очень сильно ускорено.

Вот тестовый пример:

```
function r_no($text)
{
    $text = strtolower($text); // Текст теряет свой изначальный вид!!!
    $array = array(
        'blacksite',
        'blacksite1'
    );

    $text = str_replace($array, '****', $text);
    return $text;
}

function r_yes($text)
{
    $array = array(
        '%blacksite%i',
        '%blacksite1%i'
    );

    $text = preg_replace($array, '****', $text);
    return $text;
}

$text = 'Есть к примеру массив $array = array(\'blacksite.com\',...); в котором указаны запрещённые сайты, которые нужно фильтровать из текста, например заменять из на {Ссылка удалена} и можно проверять к примеру через regexp и после проходом in_array(), но зная что есть такая защита могут написать и Blacksite*com и blackSite com или с пробелом или * после любой буквы в слове blacksite, как правильнее и лучше\надёжнее фильтровать?';

$start = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    $kk = r_no($text);
}
echo "<pre>\n";
echo "Время str_replace: ", microtime(TRUE) - $start, "\n";
echo "</pre>\n";

$start = microtime(TRUE);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
{
    $kk = r_yes($text);
}
echo "<pre>\n";
echo "Время preg_replace: ", microtime(TRUE) - $start, "\n";
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Время str_replace: 6.5153729915619 <-- ЖУТЬ О_о

Время preg_replace: 0.18601012229919
```

Если я закомментирую строку `$text = strtolower($text); // Текст теряет свой изначальный вид!!!`, то получу такой результат:

```
Время str_replace: 0.16600894927979

Время preg_replace: 0.18501091003418
```

**P.S.** Смело используйте для данной задачи регулярные выражения ;)

Comment: Как раз юзаю PHP 7, спасибо за ответ))

Comment: Увеличил кол-во символов до 10 000 и preg_replace в правду справляется быстрее

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6aabfb3874c906529886f987de5a27b5f6df74e вы немного лукавите, оценивая алгоритм по времени, так как это в корне не правильно, так как на время выполнения операции влияет множество факторов мощность компьютера, загруженность процессора, выделенное количество оперативной памяти, выполнение чего либо запустите скрипт и увидите что, время скачет. Что бы дать оценку алгоритму вы можете провести анализ по данным и количеству операций над ними. В моём случае это прямоленейная функция, в случае регулярки это экспонента длины строки.

Comment: @Naumov, даже если это особенность моего компьютера, а не онлайн эмулятора, вы все равно замучаетесь писать код для фильтра на строковых функциях по сравнению с регулярными выражениями :Р

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сделал так

в массив с запрещёными ссылками пишем что ссылку без `http:`,`https` и домена
и простым `str_replace` заменять

```
$arrayBlock = array(
     'blacksite',
     'blacksite1'
);

$text = str_replace($array,'****',$text);
```

в результате получаем что тотипотакого `http://***.com`,`*** .com`,`****com`и т.д.Объигрываеться таким способом большинство случаев кроме случаев написания `b l a c k s i t e . c o m` но этот случай тоже можно обыграть к примеру так

```
$text = str_replace(" ","",$text);
if(strpos($text,$blacksite) !== false) {
   echo 'forbidden'; die;
}
```

т.е. просто запрещая публиковать любые сообщения содержащие запрещённые ссылки. Для высоконагруженого проэкта лучше использовать массив символов для синетизации, и послеэтого `strpos` если это не всоко нагруженый проэкт можно использовать и регулярку для синетизации и сравнения.

Comment: Совершенно свободно можно в сообщении писать и `Blacksite.com`, и `blackSite.com` и человек по этим ссылкам уйдет на нужный сайт, а `str_replace` или `strpos` от этого не спасут! Опять же если проверять при сохранении сообщения, а не при выводе, не такая уж большая нагрузка регулярками добавляется к остальным проверкам текста.

Comment: @Visman регулярка рекурсивно идёт по символьно. К сожалению в php это не оператор а функция. Если смотреть в пределах строки в 50 символов это нормально. Но если взять символовбольше допусти 300-400 то мы получим значительное потребление памяти и процессорного времени. Ну и ваше замечание конструктивно и решаеться проблемма `strtolower`